# ON DELETE SET NULL on self referencing relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, self-referencing-table

I have the table with one `primary key` and one `foreign key` referencing the `same table primary key`.
 i.e there are parents and childs in the same table. In sql sever there are three options for the delete rule. But it is only possible to set `"NO ACTION"` delete rule. I understand that it is not possible to set the `"cascade" delete` because of cycles and chaining. But why the other options are not allowed? Especially the `"SET NULL"` one.

Right now I have to do this manually. I have to find the child records and set the foreign key on null. After that I can delete the parent. Why is it not possible to set the rule for it?

Comment: in your case i think that **trigger on delete** do what you want. look this [CREATE TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: I'd like to avoid creating trigger but that might be the only solution at the end of the day. I wanted to know if there is some DDL workaround to force sql server allow "ONDELETE SET NULL". And if it is not possible, why then? Because I can't see the reasons for disabling "ONDELETE SET NULL" be the same as for disabling "ONDELETE CASCADE". There are no cycles nor multiple cascade paths. I just want to be sure there is no logical reason before I post it to MS wishlist.

Comment: @matti i found this [on delete set null](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-set-null-and-set-default-with-foreign-key-constraints)

Answer (score 3):

Because it cannot perform two actions on the same table together which are:

-delete the parent.

-update the children.

> A mutating table is a table that is being modified by an UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT statement, or a table that might be updated by the effects of a DELETE CASCADE constraint.

you can overcome doing it manually by creating a procedure that would hold the parent key to delete the record and set the children to NULL.

```
procedure(parent_id) --takes the id as a parameter

   update table set null where foreign_key = parent_id;

   delete from table where id = parent_id;

end;
```

Comment: Can you cite a reference?